# JQuery dataTable always show all records in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using a jquery dataTable(not DataTable) in my view. I have

"paging": true,

"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]

in the javascript file. However, the table still shows all records in one page. I expected to see 10 records in each page.

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Somebody asked the similar question and one common reason was because jquery.js was rendered twice. But it seems I don't have this problem.

Can anybody give some suggestion? Thanks very much.

Comment: did you try including the [pageLength](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) option?

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me, in my case:

```
table_users = $ ('#table_current_user').DataTable 
({
    processing: true, 
    Serverside: true, 
    scrollX: true, 
    Paginate: true,
})
```

Removing the Serverside option, the logs are displayed in order (10 in 10)